# what does php use by default for it's curl cookie file?

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE and CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR can be set via curl_setopt() but I'm curious if there's a way to see what they are by default when they're not explicitly set.

Any ideas?

Comment: They're just NULL, or more exactly null pointers in [libcurl](https://github.com/bagder/curl/tree/master/src), since PHP doesn't keep the option list itself.